# Pytesseract OCR detecting in game name tags

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm doing a school project using OCR to detect where player nametags are in screenshots from the browser game shellshockers. I have OCR running with pytesseract, but the model is very finnicky about when it does/doesn't detect the nametags as text. Is there a way to edit the images for better recognition? I've added an example [image](https://i.imgur.com/7rlSojD.png), where I would be trying to read the nametag of the player "IMAGINE DYING". Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

I have used a very basic model however the results that we receive are not highly accurate and are ineffective for our project.

Comment: The link does not point to a image.

Comment: It's possible that you might have access to the text data itself if you launch the browser through, or attach to it via, a browser automation tool like Selenium. You still would be able to play the game, while also running commands. Then, you can grab anything you want right out of the DOM or otherwise.

Comment: Show us the binarized image you produced from that full color image. Perhaps you relied on [Otsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method). Tesseract will have an easier time of it if you send just a cleaned up greyscale image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: maybe you should use `OpenCV` - [Improving OCR Results with Basic Image Processing - PyImageSearch](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/11/22/improving-ocr-results-with-basic-image-processing/)